# Answer made community wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/210400/38268)  was made into community wiki. I flagged for moderator attention to undo it, but nothing has happened. Can a moderator please undo the CW status of it?

Thanks.

Comment: How did it become CW?

Comment: In the future, flag to remove this instead of posting on meta (I saw that you did flag, but doing both isn't necessary). I'm going to delete this question in a day.

Comment: Even the [revisions](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/210400/revisions) don't show anything indicating it...